# Joomla! 3 installation freezes at creating database table

Tags: mysql, installation, wampserver, freeze, joomla3.0

I am trying to install Joomla! 3.2.1 on my system but the installation freezes half way through. I've downloaded and installed the Wamp Server 2.4 and wanted to locally install Joomla! 3.2.1, but the installation freezes and doesn't finish.

[image: browser screenshot of hanging install]

It stops short of finishing the installation during the "creating database tables" task: it just stays on this bit seemingly forever.

Increasing the max execution time in `php.ini` and restarting the wamp didn't help.

My Wamp 2.4 uses:

- MySQL 5.6.12
- php 5.4.16
- Apache 2.4.4

How can I get the installer to go past this point?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This problem occurring most usually at Joomla 3.x.
To solve this go to `wamp\www\Your joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql` and open Joomla.sql file find the term

> "ENGINE=InnoDB"

and replace ALL with

> "ENGINE=MyIsam"

MyIsam is more supported and compatible with Joomla.

***Do also the same with (sample_data.sql) file, if it's quickstart setup.***

Comment: Is it possible that Joomla is that dumb?

Comment: Thanks, i face exact prob, now got solution. i would like to what is actual root for this problem, in the sense, if we remove innodb, then we could not able tow create any relationship for the mention table.

Comment: Changing timeout is a better solution

Comment: @Universe, the same with this approach ;-)

Comment: @Chiz as you think but your comment doesn't add any help. Post a answer if you think different than me, and leave the people choose what fit on their problem

Comment: @Universe, I tried this approach - doesn't work. I tried approach below - it works. This is my help.

Comment: @Chiz that you say doesn't make "Changing timeout" a better solution...
(as you comment in the beginning).
But is an alternative, If my approach doesn't work with you. But are you sure that you apply the second approach having reset  first the changes from my approach?

Comment: @Universe Is there a way without changing the ENGINE.  Because we use relationships in our database model and we want to use INNODB engine in our custom component...

Comment: @Malaiselvan as far as I know, not. You should consider change your model, if you can

Comment: @Universe Thanks... I used your solution and after installing I changed back all joomla tables back to INNODB.... It works great so far...

Comment: @Malaiselvan nice to hear that!

Comment: @Malaiselvan Would have been a lot simpler to just increase the timeout in PHP than all that engine changing

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that PHP has timed out. By default WAMP comes with the php variable `max_execution_time = 30`

Look at your `php error log` and it should make this error fairly obvious.

So edit your `php.ini` file, using the wampmanager menu system

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Find the parameter

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

And change it to

```
max_execution_time = 200
```

Then restart Apache, so it see's these changes.

Once the install has completed go back and change it back to a value no more than `60`.

Comment: tnx that worked for me ;) (you must restart the Apache after every change...)

Comment: yep this one is better. on xampp chaing max_execution_time to 200 solved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me too. Guyz, this seems a better option, 'cause you don't have to change anything from the default Joomla! Installation.

Comment: The crucial part of that answer is to stop and restart your Apache! Otherwise it wont work! At least that is what happened to me

Comment: it is really a better solution because it is not forcing to use MyIsam, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Most of user's are facing This problem when installing Joomla 3.x. I have also faced this problem. Then i found the solution to do some configuration changes in my php.ini file and joomla's mysql file.
i did following changes :

```
in php.ini file

Output_Buffering=Off 
Display_Errors=Off 
and in wamp\www\Your joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql\Joomla.sql
replaced all the occurence of "ENGINE=InnoDB" with "ENGINE=MyIsam"
```

Now my joomla demo site has been working fine

Comment: maybe the changes of `Output_Buffering=Off and Display_Errors=Off` are not necessary..

Answer (score 2):

In case changing `max_execute_time` or replacing `InnoDB` didn't work for you, try to install it in different browser like Opera. Worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the following changes:

```
"ENGINE=InnoDB"
```

and replace ALL with

```
"ENGINE=MyIsam"
```

and then I increased the execution time in php.ini file to 200, as pointed in earlier answers.

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

And change it to

```
max_execution_time = 200
```

Further, in php.ini file

```
Output_Buffering=Off 
Display_Errors=Off
```

This did the job!

Comment: maybe the changes of `Output_Buffering=Off`, `Display_Errors=Off` and `max_execution_time` are not necessary..

Comment: any idea if i try to do the changes in a hosted server, where to change the php.ini file ?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue of hanging of the installation of joomla 3.4.5 on my windows machine.

```
OS: Win 8.1 x64
XAMPP v3.2.1
Joomla: 3.4.5
```

I tried to perform the same 5-6 times. Then, after googling a lot came to conclusion that it can be resolved just my modifying 2 parameters in the php.ini config file usually located inside the

```
<XAMPP_INSTALL_DIR>/php/php.ini

memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 200
```

It worked.
So, there is no need to modify the InnoDB engine to MyIsam. 
Base installation works well. Just the issue with our default settings of the php configuration.