# Error installing Joomla 3.2.3 on wampserver 2.4 windows 8

Tags: php, joomla, wampserver, joomla3.0

I am trying to install version 3.2.3 of joomla. 
when I've finished configuring Joomla, installation starts and stays at half. 
I have installed wampserver version 2.4 with php 5.4.12, mysql version 5.6.12 
and apache 2.4.4 
Anyone know what happens?

Comment: You may please add tags like php to attract more people. Moreover, the question is best-suited on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or http://www.joomla.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you please be a be a little bit more specific? What do you mean by "stops at half"? Which page exactly? Is it by any chance whilst setting up the database? Have you tried installing Joomla on Xampp instead?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510660/joomla-3-installation-freezes-at-creating-database-table/21510700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal problem is that PHP times out during the install.

Check the php error log and it should tell you this if this is happening.

To increase the allowed PHP runtime, do this :-

Edit php.ini ( use the wampmanager menus to do this so you edit the correct file )

Find `max_execution_time = 30` and change it to `max_execution_time = 600`

Once the install has completed change it back to no more than `60`