# Errror creating joomla tables in xamp

Tags: mysql, joomla

i don't know if this is a dumb question but i have a problem during the installation of joomla on my local web server "xamp". I've just drag the installation folder of joomla on my htdocs folder and i've run it and after put all the credential for the database and for the username and password of my future access in the admin control page i've pressed the button "Install" and i saw that the process of the installation stop during the creation of the tables in my database.

So i check on phpmyadmin the database and i saw that only few tables was created. 
Is there someone that have my same error?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510660/joomla-3-installation-freezes-at-creating-database-table

Comment: Make sure that you're using the latest version of Xampp

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Joomla 3, is that right?

Did you tried to execute the SQL direct from the phpMyAdmin?
You can find the installation SQL in the folder installation\sql\mysql\joomla.sql

Executing from the interface will give you valuable information, about if the problem is about the database or something else.

I would try that first.

Good Luck.